# How do I assign a command to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am new to Python and when writing a loop module i bumped into the problem that I can't to find a way to put a command in the 'loopme' (it just gets ignored and then the script goes on). I hope you guys can help me with my problem. Thanks in advance :D!

```
   def loop(loopme):
        start = 'y'
        while True:
            start != 'y'
            restart = input('restart? (y/n) ')
            if restart == 'y':
                start = 'y'
            elif restart == 'n':
                break
            else:
                print('invalid input')
                continue

            loopme   #it works with print('hi')

            if start == 'y':
                start = 'n'
```

Comment: _put a command_ ? You mean assigning a value to `loopme`?

Comment: @VasilisG. i think he means some code like similar to a delegate

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to execute `loopme` before the last `if` statement, you can pass any function to `loop` as a parameter and then call it.

Demo:

```
>>> def loop(loopme):
...     # some code
...     loopme()
...     # some more code
... 
>>> def loopme(): print('hi  there, i am loopme!')
... 
>>> loop(loopme)
hi  there, i am loopme!
```

Note that you must explicitly call `loopme` by adding the `()`, just stating the function name will do nothing useful.

(Also note that it is not necessary to call `loop`'s argument `loopme`, you could have named it `some_function` and then call `some_function()` in `loop`'s body.)

> is there a way to make the 'def loopme()' ask what it is supposed to say?

Of course!

```
>>> def asker():
...     print(input('What do you want to say? '))
... 

>>> loop(asker)
What do you want to say? Hello World!
Hello World!
```

Comment: is there a way to make the 'def loopme()' ask what it is supposed to say?

Comment: def loopme(): print(raw_input("Say what you want"))

Comment: @FeedWizard yes, `loopme` can be any function. So you could ask the user for input in `loopme`. Ajay2588 already gave you an example. (Use `input` instead of `raw_input` in Python 3.)

Comment: @FeedWizard added an example to my post

Comment: how do i make loopme a non print command been trying for 30mins now and cant find a way to do it

Comment: @FeedWizard This is the last follow-up question I will answer. By putting something else in the definition of `loopme`.